# Redirect link to new link with anchor tag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have the url: www.example.com/test/here.

I want to re-direct it to: www.example.com/test2/home#here.

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule  /apply$ www.example.com/test2/home#here [R, NE]
```

But I am currently getting a server error. Sorry I am not very good with htaccess files.

Comment: And you expect `/apply$` to match `test/here` _because …?_

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a server error because of this:

```
[R, NE]
```

You can't have spaces in your rewrite flags, it confuses mod_rewrite and makes it think it's an extra parameter, thus making it think you've not closed your flags with a `]`.

Besides that, you're regex pattern: `/apply$` *will never match* `/test/here`. Perhaps, you should try `^test/here$` instead.